# 3 tables many to many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, pivot, many-to-many

I'm making a website in Laravel and ran into the following issue.

I have three tables: **User**, **JobOffer**, and **Company**
Many users have many job offers.

I have created a ManyToMany-relationship between Users and Joboffers.

User model:

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\JobOffer')->withTimestamps();
```

JobOffer model:

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')->withTimestamps();
```

But the problem is the Joboffers table has a column `company_id` (because 
of the relationship between Company and Joboffer) and the relationship between Users-Joboffer returns the id of the company. But I would like to get the name of the company.

Thanks a lot!

**Update**:

My models:

## App\User.php

```
public function job_offers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\JobOffer')->withTimestamps();
}
```

## App\JobOffer.php

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')->withTimestamps();
}

public function company()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Company');
}
```

## App\Company.php

```
public function job_offers()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\JobOffer');
}
```

The user **IGP** was right. Thanks a lot IGP.

Comment: Please provide more details about your models. Their primary keys and foreign keys mostly.

Comment: I've updated the question for other user in the same problem. IGP thanks a lot, you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until more details are provided, I'm assuming the relationships are as follows:

- **User** model and **JobOffer** model have an M:N relationship
- **Company** model and **JobOffer** model have a 1:M relationship

```php
# App\User.php
public function job_offers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\JobOffer')->withTimestamps();
}
```

```php
# App\JobOffer.php
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')->withTimestamps();
}

public function company()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Company');
}
```

```php
# App\Company.php
public function job_offers()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\JobOffer');
}
```

From these relationships you can get the company name like so:

```php
use App\User;

$user = User::with('job_offers.company')->where(...)->first();
```

The resulting object will look like this:

```php
App\User {
  id: 1,
  created_at: "",
  updated_at: "",
  job_offers: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {
    all: [
      App\JobOffer {
        id: 85,
        company_id: 36,
        created_at: "",
        updated_at: "",
        pivot: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot {
          job_offer_id: 85,
          user_id: 1,
          created_at: "",
          updated_at: "",
        },
        company: App\Company {
          id: 36,
          name: "Company1"
          created_at: "",
          updated_at: "",
        },
      },
      App\JobOffer {
        id: 90,
        company_id: 44,
        created_at: "",
        updated_at: "",
        pivot: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot {
          job_offer_id: 90,
          user_id: 1,
          created_at: "",
          updated_at: "",
        },
        company: App\Company {
          id: 44,
          name: "Company2"
          created_at: "",
          updated_at: "",
        },
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

All you need to do is loop through the User's job offers to get each company name.

```php
@foreach($user->job_offers as $job_offer)
    Company name: {{ $job_offer->company->name }}
@endforeach
```